# how to solve this issue:Cannot resolve the collation

Tags: sql-server-2012

I used this storeproceure.In this procedure am using temp table.Above error came while execution procedure.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetAllBranchName]
(
    @code nvarchar(4),
    @bankcode varchar(9)
)
as
begin
    if(@code<>'A')
    begin
        create table #tmprecs (branchcode nvarchar(50))

        insert #tmprecs
        select distinct BranchCode from PenMaster 
        where SUBSTRING(BranchCode,4,3)=@bankcode and Tocode=@code

        select b.RBI_CODE as RBI_Code,b.BR_NAME as BR_Name from #tmprecs a 
        inner join NEWRECSBRANCH b
        on a.branchcode=b.RBI_CODE
        where SUBSTRING(BranchCode,4,3)=@bankcode

        drop table #tmprecs
    end

    if(@code='A')
    begin
        select RBI_CODE,BR_NAME from NEWRECSBRANCH
        where SUBSTRING(RBI_CODE,4,3)=@bankcode order by BR_NAME
    end

end
```

i got this error:Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

i added replication also .so how will cleared this issue

Comment: use collate keyword to force the main collation

Comment: i used that keyword but not working ..is there any other options

Comment: try to change type from nvarchar to varchar